# Hortonworks Hue Oozie Streaming Job Fails when using "Add File" section (shells scripts)

Tags: hadoop, streaming, oozie, hue

I have installed HDP 2.x, and hue. (2 hosts)

I need to solve this issue as I'm new to oozie workflows.
I followed example here: http://www.oraclealchemist.com/news/hadoop-streaming-hue-oozie-workflows-hive/
It works perfectly if I have mapper and reducers in all hosts at respective paths only. I see ambari-qa smoke test of oozie is fine but when I submit a streaming job from Hue UI for Oozie, where mapper and reducers where shell scripts which performs word count (term frequency) and I wanted to use "Add File" (-file in hadoop command line) section in Oozie workflow editor and upload mapper and reducers to HDFS. After this change and submitting this job, there was an error. I get the following error for all attempts of map tasks:

> 2013-12-16 19:21:24,278 ERROR [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed: configuration exception
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1387201627160_0006/container_1387201627160_0006_01_000002/./maptf.sh":
>   java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

This means it can't able to find mapper and reducer in that path where oozie/mapred/yarn will create files onfly. Do I have any oozie configuration and workflow issues? (logs by email: sandeepboda91083@gmail.com)

In HDFS, I have all paths and files setup correctly under root user.

Note: I can able to run streaming jobs without oozie as:

```
cd /root/mrtest/
ls
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 235 Dec 11 11:37 maptf.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 273 Dec 11 11:37 redtf.sh

hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-76.jar -D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=1 -input crane_in1 -output crane_out2 -file ./maptf.sh -mapper maptf.sh -file ./redtf.sh -reducer redtf.sh
```

It seems I cant attach logs here. Please mail me for files and logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the same problems as these users on the [Hue list](https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!searchin/hue-user/No%2420such%2420file%2420or%2420directory%7Csort%3arelevance).

If you edited the file with File Browser they might be corrupted because of some non Unix new lines. You should upload them straight and not modify them or use a more recent version of [Hue](http://gethue.com) (3.5 at this time of writing).

Comment: Yes, I edited shell scripts in windows notepad/wordpad and uploaded via "Add File" upload method. This means for each end of line I see \r\n appended and this causes the error. I need to do dos2unix conversion and made it work. But why the error message is misleading? *"No such file or directory"*